# Use Xpath to Get Row Number

Tags: html, xpath

[View of the table and first row] Ultimately, I need to click on an edit button in td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWMzw.png) within a tr that is dynamic.

My plan was to find that tr[#] based on the text in td[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hpUE.png) (the email address that is the identifier).

```
//table/tr/td[2][contains(text(),'me@address.com')]
```

[The HTML code] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hpUE.png) Correctly highlights td[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hpUE.png) of the row I need to capture. I'd like to get that tr# and then use the next line to click the element in tr[#]/td[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWMzw.png), but I am stuck.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a representative sample of the html you are working with.

Comment: Pictures attached (as hyperlinks, sorry)

Comment: [You really shouldn't attach pictures...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9448090)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'preceding-sibling' to select the desired element

```
//table/tr/td[2][contains(text(),'me@address.com')]/preceding-sibling::td
```

This will look for your element and then select the preceding td containing your desired link

Also it is worth noting that the '(text(),'me@address.com')' attribute you are using is case sensitive